# CSV/TSV comment lines d3

Tags: javascript, comments, d3.js

I am trying to read tsv data using d3. However, my data has comment lines as follows

```
#Comment line
@Different comment line
x    y
1    2
4    2
5    1
```

Is it possible to get d3 to ignore those lines?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

D3 has no built-in way to ignore comment lines. Your easiest option is going to be to pre-process the file before parsing with D3:

```
d3.text(url, 'text/csv', function(csv) {
    // remove comment rows with regex - not fully tested, but should work
    csv = csv.replace(/^[#@][^\r\n]+[\r\n]+/mg, '');
    var data = d3.csv.parse(csv);

    // ... now the rest of your code ...
});
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! I found out you can do something similar with Jquery using $.get(url) to get the data, split it by \n then process each line

Comment: There is one parenthesis that must be suppressed after the replace word but stackoverflow doesn't let me do it as it has a threshold of 6 characters change minimum. Thanks !